# Combine cells with binary values in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

Imagine I have a couple of eight cells which all contain a binary value; so it shall be something like Cell A1 has value 0; Cell A2 has value 1; Cell A3 has value 0; etc.

What I would like to have is a Cell which combines these values to a e.g. 01011011. How can I do that in Excel?

Comment: Do you want to SUM the values or put them in order in a cell?

Comment: I want to put them in order. I already solved it using `CONCATENATE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CONCATENATE` Function to do this:-

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1,G1,H1)
```

### Result:

```
01011011
```

Answer (score -1):

With Excel 2016 and later or Office 365, the formula could be:

```
=CONCAT(A1:H1)
```

Comment: Note: Concat is just a shorter version of Concatenate. They perform the same function. The shorter version was introduced in Excel versions 2016 and later, including 365.